# MySQL incorrect equality casting bigint to char

Tags: mysql, type-conversion, cast

Why is the following statement true in MySQL?

`CAST(544553000004545482 AS CHAR) = 544553000004545446`

--Background--

I am querying a database with user IDs stored as `VARCHAR(255)`, but my program represents these IDs as integers, so SQL is doing type coercion whenever I have a WHERE condition such as `WHERE userId = %s`. I noticed recently the above, incorrect result, because I got data for the user ending in 5482 when querying for the user ending in 5446.

I know the solution here is to either convert the database to a BIGINT column, or have my program cast to a string before querying, but I'd like to understand why the above is true? I'm guessing it has to do with a bit precision error. I noticed any value from 544553000004545441 - 544553000004545503 (inclusive, so a range of 63) registers as equal, so if SQL is converting somewhere to a lower bit int than the 2**64 of a BIGINT that could explain the truncation.

Comment: My guess would be that the two operands are different type (char vs signed bigint) so in order to compare them, they are both cast to float or double.

Comment: The moral of this story: (1) don't store numbers in VARCHAR, (2) if you need numbers with lots of digit, use DECIMAL.

Comment: Agreed. Obligatory "this database was here when I got here" ; )

Comment: What Rick said above, in different words: if you need long strings of digits as IDs, it's fine to store them as VARCHAR - as they are not really numbers (you would never add or multiply such IDs). But then let the applications treat them as strings as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm shooting myself in the foot, why does it hurt?

This is [by design](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/type-conversion.html):

> In all other cases, the arguments are compared as floating-point (double-precision) numbers. For example, a comparison of string and numeric operands takes place as a comparison of floating-point numbers.

You are hitting the limit of representation of your values by [double-precision floating point numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format), given the exponent value.

Comment: Ah, the 11 exponent bits of FP64 explains the precision. I had done the napkin math to figure out 53 bits were needed for steps of 64 at this scale, but that only further confused me. +1 for clear and cheeky answer :)

Comment: @Eric - DOUBLE:  1 bit sign, 11 bits exponent (biased), 53 bits of precision, including a "hidden bit".  Equivalent to _about_ 16 decimal digits.  `FLOAT`: 1 + 8 + 24; about 7 decimal digits.  BIGINT UNSIGNED: 64 bits; BIGINT SIGNED: 63 bits.  DECIMAL:  _up to_ 63 (or is it 64) _decimal_ digits -- a lot bigger than DOUBLE and BIGINT.